# How to preselect options in SELECT helper in web2py

Tags: web2py

when creating multiple select input with SELECT, OPTION helpers, I want to preselect some options, I tried following

```
OPTION('myOption', _value=val, value=[v1, v2])
```

extrapolating from the docs, but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"value" is an attribute of the "SELECT" helper.

From the documentation :

**web2py make a distinction between "_value" (the value of the OPTION), and "value" (the current value of the enclosing select). If they are equal, the option is "selected".**

http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views?search=OPTION%28

For example :

```
SELECT(
    OPTION('Option1', _value='1'),
    OPTION('Option2', _value='2')
    , value='2')
```

Will select "Option2" whereas

```
SELECT(
    OPTION('Option1', _value='1'),
    OPTION('Option2', _value='2')
    , value='2')
```

Will select "Option1"

Comment: ok so in above if I want to pre select multiple options; can I pass `value=[1,2]`?

Comment: Yes you can, but given https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/html.py#L1928 

you have to add the "_multiple" parameter.
For example : SELECT(OPTION('Option1', _value='1'),OPTION('Option2', _value='2'), value=['1','2'], _multiple=True)