# Preselecting Options not working in web2py

Tags: select, web2py

I have looked at the documentation at http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views?search=OPTION%28 and I have looked at the previous question [How to preselect options in SELECT helper in web2py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999852/how-to-preselect-options-in-select-helper-in-web2py), but my selects have not been working properly.

I make the select:

```
 select = SELECT(_name = attr)
```

I populate it by appending options in a loop

```
 ...
 option = OPTION(the_string, _value=str(row.id))
 select.append(option)
 ...
```

I set the selected value for the select
     select.value = str(selected_value)

But the select does not have anything pre-selected.  In the html, the correct option is not marked 'selected'. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`value` is an argument of `SELECT.__init__` -- it is not an attribute that can simply be set after the object is created. If you want to change the `selected` attribute of an option after it has been created, you can do:

```
select.element('option[value=%s]' % 
    str(selected_value))['_selected'] = str(selected_value)
```

Or just specify the selected option when creating the OPTION object:

```
OPTION(the_string, _value=row.id, _selected=True)
```